# Samsung ml1250 stopped working

Tags: 11.10, printing

Printer stopped working (Samsung ml1250)! I dont know what to do with them! I tried to reinstall ubuntu 11.10 but printer doesn't work! Printer fully work on Windows Xp! Please help me))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Samsung driver for your printer. Go to http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/black-and-white-laser-printers/ML-1250, and download the driver for linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot!))) But what was happend?? In ubuntu 11.04 it worked

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. My guess is that ubuntu 11.04 came with a Samsung driver, which was removed by default in ubuntu 11.10